# UIView is nil in prepareForSegue method

Tags: ios, swift, class, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

sorry for confusing title, I didn't know how to make it more meaningfull.

I was implementing information window using this example: [github](https://github.com/TotemChris/DimBackground)

I have added few labels into popView and linked them to secondaryVieController.

I have amended prepareForSegue method in PrimaryViewController to:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showInfo" {

            let info = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondaryViewController
           info.adrLabel.text = branch.address
            info.nameLabel.text = branch.name
            info.telLabel.text = branch.tel

          dim(.In, alpha: dimLevel, speed: dimSpeed)
   }
}
```

But when I run it i get error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

it is because info.popupView is nil.

But can you explain me how should I set it? And why it is working fine if there are no any additional labels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method where you will be access this

```
info.adrLabel.text = branch.address
info.nameLabel.text = branch.name
info.telLabel.text = branch.tel
```

values will be `viewDidLoad()` of `SecondaryViewController`.

You need to create variables and assign values in those variables and in the viewDidLoad() you can use those variables to assign the value to your labels.

Comment: yes, sure it is working! will be able to accept in two minutes. but why it is happening? uiview is not loaded yet and that is reason why I can not assign labels inside view? or view? thanks again

Comment: Your view is not initialized at `prepareForSegue` method, every `UIViewController` view will be initialized in viewDidLoad, and whenever you will use optional binding on a variable and got that variable as nil your app will get crashed.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting nil because you are trying to set values before the view has loaded from your prepareForSegue method. Instead, setup some variables in your SecondaryViewController to hold the values and set up your labels in viewDidLoad:

```
    class SecondaryViewController {
        var address: String?
        var name: String?
        var tel: String?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        adrLabel.text = address
        nameLabel.text = name
        telLabel.text = tel
        }
    }
```

Now all you need to do in your prepareForSegue is:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showInfo" {

        let info = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondaryViewController
       info.address = branch.address
        info.name = branch.name
        info.tel = branch.tel

      dim(.In, alpha: dimLevel, speed: dimSpeed)
    }
   }
```

Comment: thank you! I voted up your answer as well but our colleague's answer was first :)

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you should not try to manipulate another view controller's views directly. That violates the principle of encapsulation. You should consider them private.

Instead, add properties to your destination view controller and set those properties. Then in your destiination view controller's viewWillAppear method install the values from those properties into the appropriate views.

That way if you later change your view controller's views you only have to change the code in one place (the view controller)

(Plus, in situations like your prepareForSegue function, it doesn't work.)

Comment: thank you Duncan for such great explanation! I voted up your answer